# Integrate: Mathematica does nothing, not even repeat the code!

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I need to calculate the following integral:

$$ 
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}da\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}db\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy~e^{\frac{-(b^{2}+(a-10g)^{2})}{g^{2}-1}}e^{\frac{-(y^{2}+(10g-x)^{2})}{g^{2}-1}}(0.3+0.7\frac{(b^{2}+(a-10g)^{2})}{g^{2}-1})(0.3+0.7\frac{(y^{2}+(10g-x)^{2})}{g^{2}-1})
$$ 
The corresponding mathematica code is

```
Integrate[E^(-(b^2 + (a - 10 g)^2)/(g^2 - 1)) E^(-((10 g - x)^2 + y^2)/(g^2 - 1)) (0.3 + 0.7 (b^2 + (a - 10 g)^2)/(g^2 - 1)) (0.3 + 
0.7 ((10 g - x)^2 + y^2)/(g^2 - 1)) E^-((a - x)^2 + (b - y)^2), {a, -∞, ∞}, {b, -∞, ∞}, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, +∞}, Assumptions -> g > 1]
```

Mathematica gives nothing. It does not even repeat the integral form. Actually the calulation is finished with a beep and when I define a number (say, 0.3) using a symbol, the symbol becomes undefined.

Comment: [Quit the kernel](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/QuitKernel.html) and try again. Let us know the result

Comment: Under the Help menu, there's Why the Beep?... Try it. I'm guess the integral crashed the kernel.

Comment: Split the integral in two, dependant on `a`, `b` and `x`,`y`, it would make the symbolic integration easier. I've managed to integrate one but not two at the same time.

Comment: Does this do it? int1 = Integrate[E^(-((10 g-x)^2+y^2)/(g^2-1)) (3/10+7/10 ((10 g-x)^2+y^2)/(g^2-1)) E^-((a-x)^2 + (b-y)^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions->g>1] // Simplify; Integrate[
  int1 E^(-(b^2+(a-10 g)^2)/(g^2-1)) (3/10+7/10 (b^2 + (a-10 g)^2)/(g^2 -1)), {a, -Infinity, Infinity}, {b, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions->g>1] // Simplify

Comment: "when I define a number (say, 0.3) using a symbol, the symbol becomes undefined" indicates that the kernel crashed. Unfortunately, that happens often. In such cases, re-writing the expression is advisable.

Comment: Or replace both your 0.3+0.7 with 3/10+7/10 and the quadruple integral seems to complete just fine giving exactly the same result as doing the integration in two steps.

Comment: @Bill Thank you. The replacement idea worked just fine.

Comment: This result can't be right. If you calculate the Integral with NIntegrate for given values of g, (e.g. 1.1,2,10), you always get different values compared to inserting this g in your analytic result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I use exact values for `0.3` and `0.7`, it works:

```
Integrate[
 E^(-(b^2 + (a - 10 g)^2)/(g^2 - 1)) E^(-((10 g - x)^2 + y^2)/(g^2 - 
       1)) (3/10 + 7/10 (b^2 + (a - 10 g)^2)/(g^2 - 1)) (3/10 + 
    7/10 ((10 g - x)^2 + y^2)/(g^2 - 1)) E^-((a - x)^2 + (b - y)^2),
 {a, -∞, ∞}, {b, -∞, ∞}, {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, +∞}, 
 Assumptions -> g > 1]
```

After a minute or so I get this:

```
(*  ((-1 + g^2)^2 (29 - 88 g^2 + 109 g^4) π^2)/(50 (-1 + 2 g^2)^3)  *)
```

When using an exact solver, it is better to use exact numbers such as `3/10` instead of `0.3`.  The approximate numbers `0.3` are represented by floating-point numbers that are subject to round-off error:

```
(0.3 + 0.6) - 0.9
(*  -1.11022*10^-16  *)
```

And such errors can throw off exact solvers.