# Why won't Mathematica evaluate my integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I would like to integrate:

```
Integrate[
  1/((0.64*E^(2*(a/d)^1.7)*Sqrt[Pi *a]))^3, {a, a0, ac},
  Assumptions -> {d > 0, a > 0, ac > a0 > 0}
]
```

I know this has a known solution and if I choose values for a0 and ac I get a solution.

Comment: Try using exact numbers and simpler assumptions: http://i.stack.imgur.com/u2mqU.png

Comment: Duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135542/integrate-mathematica-does-nothing-not-even-repeat-the-code (as far as using exact instead of approximate coefficients).

Answer (score 6):

```
expr[a_, d_] = 
 Hold[1/((0.64*E^(2*(a/d)^1.7)*Sqrt[Pi*a]))^3] /. 
    x_Real :> Rationalize[x, 0] // ReleaseHold // FullSimplify

(* 15625/(E^(6*(a/d)^(17/10))*(4096*a^(3/2)*Pi^(3/2))) *)
```

With the usual form of [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) the integral fails to evaluate

```
Assuming[{d > 0, ac > a0 > 0}, Integrate[expr[a, d], {a, a0, ac}]]

(* Integrate[15625/(E^(6*(a/d)^(17/10))*(4096*a^(3/2)*Pi^(3/2))), {a, a0, ac}] *)
```

Using an unusual assumption of `d > a` evaluates with a condition; however, the resulting condition is exactly the assumption that previously failed.

```
int1 = Assuming[{d > a, ac > a0 > 0}, Integrate[expr[a, d], {a, a0, ac}] // 
  Simplify]

(* ConditionalExpression[
   (1/(4096*Pi^(3/2)))*
     (15625*(2/(E^(6*(a0/d)^(17/10))*Sqrt[a0]) - 
           2/(E^(6*(ac/d)^(17/10))*Sqrt[ac]) - 
           (2*6^(5/17)*Gamma[12/17, 6*(a0/d)^(17/10)])/
             Sqrt[d] + (2*6^(5/17)*
                Gamma[12/17, 6*(ac/d)^(17/10)])/Sqrt[d])), d > 0] *)
```

Reversing the assumption on `d` also evaluates but without a condition.

```
int2 = Assuming[{a > d, ac > a0 > 0}, 
  Integrate[expr[a, d], {a, a0, ac}] // Simplify]

(* (1/(4096*Pi^(3/2)))*
   (15625*(2/(E^(6*(a0/d)^(17/10))*Sqrt[a0]) - 
         2/(E^(6*(ac/d)^(17/10))*Sqrt[ac]) - 2*6^(5/17)*
           ((1/d)^(17/10))^(5/17)*
           Gamma[12/17, 6*(a0/d)^(17/10)] + 
         2*6^(5/17)*((1/d)^(17/10))^
             (5/17)*Gamma[12/17, 6*(ac/d)^(17/10)])) *)
```

Under the appropriate assumptions, the two results are equivalent

```
int1 == int2 // Simplify[#, {d > 0, ac > a0 > 0}] &

(* True *)
```

So the integral appears to be

```
int[a0_, ac_, d_] = int2 // FullSimplify

(* (1/(2048*Pi^(3/2)))*
   (15625*(1/(E^(6*(a0/d)^(17/10))*Sqrt[a0]) - 
         1/(E^(6*(ac/d)^(17/10))*Sqrt[ac]) + 6^(5/17)*
           ((1/d)^(17/10))^(5/17)*
           (-Gamma[12/17, 6*(a0/d)^(17/10)] + 
              Gamma[12/17, 6*(ac/d)^(17/10)]))) *)
```

Numerically verifying for some random values of the parameters

```
SeedRandom[0]

And @@ Table[Module[{a0, ac, d},
   a0 = SetPrecision[RandomReal[{0, 5}], 20];
   ac = SetPrecision[a0 + RandomReal[{0, 5}], 20];
   d = SetPrecision[RandomReal[{1, 10}], 20];
   exact = int[a0, ac, d];
   Abs[(exact - Integrate[expr[a, d], {a, a0, ac}])/exact] < 10^-12], {100}]

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Integrate[1/((0.64*E^(2*(a/d)^1.7)*Sqrt[Pi*a]))^3, {a, a0, ac}, Assumptions -> d > 0 && a > 0 && ac > a0 > 0]

(*(0.682581 Gamma[-0.294118, (6. a0^1.7)/d^1.7] - 0.682581 Gamma[-0.294118, 6. (ac/d)^(17/10)])/d^0.5*)
```

I get your code to work fine if I separate the assumptions with `&&` instead of commas.

Comment: that also does the job: `Integrate[1/((0.64*E^(2*(a/d)^1.7)*Sqrt[Pi*a]))^3, {a, a0, ac}, 
 Assumptions -> {0 < a0 < ac, d > 0}]`